# picOS 18 Alarm definition

Tags: pic, rtos

In picOS 18 there is taskdesc.c file which defines alarms. There is such a definition in that file :

```
Counter Counter_list[] = 
  {
   /*******************************************************************
    * -------------------------- First counter ------------------------
    *******************************************************************/
   {
     {
       200,                                /* maxAllowedValue        */
        10,                                /* ticksPerBase           */
       100                                 /* minCycle               */
     },
     0,                                    /* CounterValue           */
     0                                     /* Nbr of Tick for 1 CPT  */
   }
  };
```

I don't understand the meaning of maxAllowedValue,ticksPerBase,minCycle,CounterValue ,Nbr of Tick for 1 CPT. I looked them on the web, on datasheets and tutorials and I have found nothing. Can you tell me what they are used for please?

Comment: PicOS18 is neither well known or easy to find.  You should include a link and the exact version in your question.  The one source I have found does not include this code - are you sure that it is from the original distribution and not added by someone else?

Answer (score 0):

They are comments - they have no meaning to the compiler. They presumably refer to the member names of the struct type `Counter` that are being initialised.  The definition of `Counter` may be enlightening.